# deploy React App locally - localhost refuses to connect

Tags: reactjs

I have referenced every other related StackOverflow thread I could find but still have not found a solution.

I've started the app locally using both `npm start` and `yarn start`. The app runs just fine:

[image]

But the localHost refuses to connect. I have restarted my computer, I have changed my port to other working ports, I can run other applications locally on those ports (port 8000, port 5000, etc). I have deleted my node_modules directory and rebuilt dependencies using `yarn`. I have not modified package.json.

What am I missing?

Comment: `http://x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0:3000` doesn't look even nearly right...

Comment: Please add more info. did you modify the package.json?

Comment: Localhost address is always `localhost:3000` or `127.0.0.1:3000` This ip address is definetly wrong. Not sure what device you have, but it should not look like this

Comment: How can I change the IP address?

Comment: Checkout this link: https://choy.medium.com/fixing-create-react-app-when-npm-fails-to-start-because-your-host-environment-variable-is-being-4c8a9fa0b461